# BIRT - Charts wont show when deployed on IE

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, internet-explorer, birt

IE version:
[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odVqK.png)

When I run the report locally on my machine on IE, it's displaying the charts okay:
[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLgAq.png)

But when its deployed on our server and called on our web app , it doesn't show the charts:
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SmTR.png)

NOTE: other reports runs okay on IE, only the report with charts, ALSO the report runs okay on CHROME and FIREFOX.

WHAT I TRIED: changed the chart format to all available formats(svg,jpg,png,bmp)

How can I fix the issue on IE?

Thanks,
NicoTing

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=809438&goto=1424151&#msg_1424151 Here for solution

Comment: @I'mLimit I dont get it, the fix there is add some codes from eclipse.ini or change some of the registry, but my problem is when deployed on our server and called on our web app using iframe , when running it from eclipse to IE no problem

Comment: Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console in IE? You could check the `src` of the iframe to see if it is correct and try to run the `src` address alone in IE to see if the charts works.

Comment: @YuZhou yes, when I copy the link of the report and paste it to other tab, its still shows nothing, but in chrome , firefox, edge , its okay.

Comment: It might be something incompatible with IE. Is there any error in console? Could you provide a simple sample of the report which can reproduce the issue in IE? So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and test it in our side. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou there is no error in the console, fyi, I also add compatibility view. but still the same

Comment: It's hard to locate the issue with only the description of the issue. FYI, I find a [similar thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2108938.aspx?Image+displaying+on+Chrome+and+Firefox+but+not+IE+11) about images not showing in IE and you could try the methods in the thread. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821587/image-not-displaying-in-ie-only) about how to debug this issue further.

Comment: @YuZhou Thank You for all the help , I will take a look on that, btw yes, the charts are images, andthe IE wont show any image from the report, even I just add an image logo , it will show that broken image.

Comment: You're welcome. You could let us know if there's any status update about the issue after trying the methods provided in the above comment. If you have solved the issue, you could also post the solution and try to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @YuZhou I tried all of the methods from the above but doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please compare the different environment settings like OS version and configuration file settings of the website between the server and your machine, it could be helpful to narrow down and find the issue. And we don't want your source code, just provide a simple sample of the page containing images. You could remove sensitive personal information. It's enough to be able to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I used the same version of BIRT from our server which is: 4.7.0.v201706222054
, the OS of our server is Linux, I am using Windows 10 , I dont know the flow of process of deploying the reports, I will ask our devops. also just an FYI, if  save the image link and then save it as , it is save as file by default , if I changed it to .jpg for example, I was able to view it on my Photos app, just in case u want to see the response of chart/image: https://i.imgur.com/Q5A6GUw.png

Comment: **1.** You deployed the app to Linux and then visit the page in IE in your Windows machine or in IE in the Linux machine? Besides, the different server system might be the cause. Maybe Linux needs different config file settings when hosting the windows-designed app. **2.** Could you please use F12 and give me the screenshot of the html code of the report with broken images in IE? If only the images in the report can't show, then the issue might with the report structure in IE. You could also compare the report html code in IE with in other browsers to see if there's any difference.

Comment: deployed the report from LINUX, visit the page from Windows IE, PS: I have no access on our server, here: https://i.imgur.com/jogs97y.png

Comment: The html code seems to be ok. It's strange that the charts can't show in IE. I'll try to contact senior engineer to check whether there is any solution. I'll let you know if there's any further information.

Comment: Can you please try using image's onload event(specific to IE) to catch the error message? It will be much more efficient to narrow down the issue than just guessing what has happened there.